# How to use inputs in the Ui part?

Tags: r, input, shiny, output

I'd like to be able to use results of an input in the Ui part of my shiny app, to set the default value and the maximum of a numericInput.

Here is the "idea" of the ui part i'd like :

```
ui <- (

 numericInput("n21","choose input1",min=0,max=100000,value=5107,step=1),
 numericInput("n22","choose input2",min=0,max=2000,value=1480.3/40),

 # here i'd like to define value and max with the result of inputs (n23) 
 numericInput(inputId="nb_rows","Number of rows to show",value=n23,min=1,max=n23)
 tableOutput(outputId = "data")
)
```

And the server part :

```
server <- function(input,output,session){
  ....
  RE <- reactive({
   n21 <- input$n21
   n22 <- input$n22
   n23 <- n21%/%n22

   return(head(data, n=input$nb_rows))
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({RE()})


}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the observe function at server to change the numericinput using an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the observe function to change the numericinput that you want to change so we will do:

```
`server <- function(input,output,session){
  ....
  RE <- reactive({
   n21 <- input$n21
   n22 <- input$n22
   n23 <- n21%/%n22

   return(n23)
  })`

`    observe({
      x <- RE()

      # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
      if (is.null(x))
        x <- character(0)

      # Can also set the label and select items
      updateNumericInput(session, "nb_rows",
                        label = "Number of rows to show",
                        value = x,
                        min = 1,
                        max = x
      )
    })`
```

And then you re-make the output table function

I hope it helps.